# Return index of nested element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have two nested `ul` which contain links.

I want to find the index of the clicked `a` within it's parent `ul`

```
<div id="main_nav">
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/url/">LINK</link></li>
            <li><a href="/url/">LINK</link></li>
            <li><a href="/url/">LINK</link></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/url/">LINK</link></li>
            <li><a href="/url/">LINK</link></li>
            <li><a href="/url/">LINK</link></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

I'm using the following code:

```
$("#main_nav ul ul a").click(function () {

    var index = $('#main_nav ul ul a').index(this);

    alert(index);
});
```

which seems to return the index of the `a` within the `parent of the parent` instead of just the `parent` (I hope that makes sense) i.e. Clicking the second link in the second `ul` returns an index of 4 instead of 1.

Could somebody explain where I'm going wrong with this? I suspect it's something simple but I can't figure it out.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get the index of the parent `li` element.  Otherwise you are getting the index of the anchor inside the list item, which will always be zero.

```
$(this.parentNode).index();
```

Comment: That's the one! Thanks Dennis